# Android Resource Linking Failed. AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: android

[Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HbV3.png)

Comment: give a hard coded value like 10dp or 20dp for dialog corner radius . Also see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please post question here, and then reference links.

Comment: Can you please post your code? and I think you should try hardcoded value.